# Split long string constant in multiple lines

Tags: javascript

I have wrote the bellow command, to generate the a data grid, it works fine with no problem, but the command is so long and if I use enter to break down the command to different rows, the jquery command will error and won't response.

Is there any way to break down this long command ?

```
       $("#mainholder ul").append('<li><p><table><th  id="contentWrapper"><font size="+2" face="Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" style="font-weight:bold" color="#FF0000">'+poId+'</font></th><th  id="contentWrapper"><img src="../images/products/iPhone.png" width="80" height="80"/></th><th  class="itSt"><font color="#FF0000" >'+itStat+'</font></th><th id="contentWrapper"><table><tr><td class = "tdinfo"><lable class="titleCs">Price : </label><input id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'"  class="contentInput" onClick="priceClk(this.id)"></td></tr><tr><td class = "tdinfo"><lable class="titleCs">Quantity : </label><input id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'"  class="contentInput" onClick="qtyClk(this.id)"></td></tr><tr><td class = "tdinfo"><lable class="titleCs">Express : </label><input id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'"  class="contentInput" onClick="expClk(this.id)"></td></tr></table></th><th id="contentWrapper"><table><tr><td><textarea id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'" onClick="offDesc()" class="commentBox"></textarea></td></tr></table></th> <th id="contentWrapper"><table><tr><td><textarea id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'" onClick="yorDesc()" class="commentBox"></textarea></td></tr></table></th>     <th id="contentWrapper"><table><tr><td> <img class="css-checkbox" src="../images/deleteIcon.png" width="20" height="20"  alt=""/></td></tr><tr><td><input id="" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td></tr></table></th></table></div></p></li>');
```

Comment: show us your break down attempt and the error

Comment: Any text editor that understands JavaScript should do it fine. Like VS + R#... If indeed your question about how to format a line in text editor of your choice please move to http://superuser.com

Comment: You can add new lines after the + symbols in your code. To insert new lines in other places you'll have to do the same: part1 + part2 + part3 + ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\` for new line.

```
$("#mainholder ul").append(
    '<li><p><table>\
     <th  id="contentWrapper">\
     <font\
         size="+2"\
         face="Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"\
         style="font-weight:bold"\
         color="#FF0000">'+poId+'</font>'......
```

Comment: +1, but you really should not use so wrong place for styles in your smaple (vs. CSS). `calss="GoodClassName"` would be better fit for SO...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes right, thanks, I'm just a new developer :)