# When use multiple selector, Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: jquery, multipleselection

I get this error.I want to add multiple selector and it gives error.what is the problem?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("nav.navbar.bootsnav.menu-style1 ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu-content .title,
                .pagination>li>a,
                .ulockd-title-icon,
    .fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-prev,
    .fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-next,
    .team-icon a,
    .twitter.style2 ul li a,
    .text-thm, .text-thm2").css("color", textColor);;
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: The problem is because you can't place line breaks within a string in JS. Use a template literal instead.

Comment: if I write in one line, it will be long and hard for reading.is there any way to write as multi lines?

Comment: `"..." + [newline] "..." + [newline]`

Comment: Yep, use a template literal as I mentioned: ```$(`nav.navbar.bootsnav.... `).css(...)```. That being said, you *really* should not have a selector that long. Put a common class on all those elements and just select that instead.

Comment: Here's another option. not my personal preference to end a line in \ as this will cause many a hidden typo - eg "\ " is different but invisible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176327/split-long-string-constant-in-multiple-lines

Comment: Looking at what you're doing `.css("color"...` looks like it should be in your .css instead (but what's `textColor`)

Comment: is there any way/tool to save time from converting multiple line? automatically adding + signs " charachters etc.

Comment: Depends on the editor, most allow block edit now - so you just ctrl+alt+cursor down then type `+ "` and it adds it to all the selected lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adress this error a couple of ways:

**Use `\` before each newline**

```js
$("nav.navbar.bootsnav.menu-style1 ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu-content .title, \
    .pagination>li>a, \
    .ulockd-title-icon, \
    .fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-prev, \
    .fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-next, \
    .team-icon a, \
    .twitter.style2 ul li a, \
    .text-thm, .text-thm2").css("color", textColor);
```

**Use string concatination**

```js
$("nav.navbar.bootsnav.menu-style1 ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu-content .title,"
  + ".pagination>li>a,"
  + ".ulockd-title-icon,"
  + ".fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-prev,"
  + ".fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-next,"
  + ".team-icon a,"
  + ".twitter.style2 ul li a,"
  + ".text-thm,"
  + ".text-thm2").css("color", textColor);
```

**Build selectors from array**

```js
let selectors = [
  "nav.navbar.bootsnav.menu-style1 ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu-content .title",
  ".pagination>li>a",
  ".ulockd-title-icon",
  ".fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-prev",
  ".fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-next",
  ".team-icon a",
  ".twitter.style2 ul li a",
  ".text-thm",
  ".text-thm2"
];
$(selectors.join(',')).css("color", textColor);
```

**Using a template literal**

```js
$(`nav.navbar.bootsnav.menu-style1 ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu-content .title,
    .pagination>li>a,
    .ulockd-title-icon,
    .fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-prev,
    .fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-next,
    .team-icon a,
    .twitter.style2 ul li a,
    .text-thm, .text-thm2`).css("color", textColor);
```

**or give them a common class**

As you can see having a lot of selectors like this is not easy to use. Not even speaking of managing changes over time.

Why not give them a common class like `changeable-color` and only select that one. Easier to read and maintain.

Comment: is there any way/tool to save time from adding plus signs?

Comment: Yes, only using one common class between all of them. I basically wrote it out for you to copy&paste, so use that for now. You can use regular expressions to rewrite code but I don't trust you are ready for that yet.

Comment: If you ask me, I prefer the way with an array of selectors. Easier to maintain in my opinion.